# Ajax request fullcalendar

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I created a calendar with fullcalendar, which allows a user to book schedules and once he has clicked on validate he will make an Ajax request to submit the data

Here is the code:

```
<script>
let event = {{ event|json_encode|raw}};

let selectEvent = null;


 //Sers a générer un calendrier
 window.onload = () => {
  let calendarElt = document.querySelector("#calendrier")

  let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElt, {
    initialView:'timeGridWeek',
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    eventConstraint: 'businessHours',
    selectConstraint: 'businessHours',
    slotDuration: '00:30:00', //durée minimum pour une prestation
     
    locale: 'fr', 
    timeZone: 'Europe/Paris',
    headerToolbar: {
      start: 'prev, next today',
      center: 'title',
      end: 'timeGridWeek',
    },
      
    businessHours: [
      {
        daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Monday to Friday
        startTime: '08:00',
        endTime: '12:00',
      },
      { daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Monday to Friday
        startTime: '13:00',
        endTime: '17:00'
      },
    ],
    selectOverlap: false,
    selectOverlap: function(event) {
    return event.rendering === 'background';
    },

    eventClick: function(info){
      if(confirm("Etes vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette reservation ?")){
        info.event.remove(); //On supprime la reservation
      }
    },

    select: function(info){
      let prestationDuration = event.dureMinutes;
      let selectDuration = (info.end - info.start) / 1000 / 60;

      if(selectDuration < prestationDuration){
        //Calculer la nouvelle date de fi 
        let newEnd = new Date(info.start.getTime() + prestationDuration * 60 * 1000);
    
        //Ajouter l'évènement au calendrier
        calendar.addEvent({
          title: event.nom,
          start: info.start,
          end: newEnd,
          color: 'red',
          textColor: 'white'
        });
      }else{
        //Si la durée de la séléction est suffisant on ajoute la prestation
        calendar.addEvent({
          title: event.nom,
          start: info.start,
          end: info.end,
          color: 'red',
          textColor: 'white'
        });
      }
      selectEvent = {
        prestation: event.nom,
        date: info.start,
        start: info.start,
        end: info.end
      };
      
    }
      
});


calendar.render();

$('#submit-button').on('click', function(){
        if(selectEvent){
          $.ajax({
            url: '/reservation/store_reservation',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(selectEvent),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(response){
              //Gérer la reponse du serveru
              alert("Réservation enregistré avec succès !");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              //Gérer l'erreur
              alert("Erreur lors de l'enregistrement de la réservation" + textStatus + ": "  
              + errorThrown);
            }
            
          });
          
        }
        
      })


  };
```

And the following code will have, for the role of creating a new reservation and adding it to the database, here is the code:

```
  #[Route("/store_reservation", name:"store_reservation", methods:["POST"])]
  public function store_reservation(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em):Response
{
if($request->getMethod() != 'POST'){
    return new JsonResponse(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Invalid request method']);
}

$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

if(!isset($data['prestation']) || !isset($data['date']) || !isset($data['dabut']) ||   !isset($data['fin'])){
    return new JsonResponse(['status' => 'erreor', 'message' => 'Missing data for reservation']);
}

//Créer une nouvelle reservation avec les donnée reçut
$reservation =new Reservation();

$reservation -> setPrestation($data['prestation']);
$reservation -> setDate(new \DateTime($data['date']));
$reservation -> setDebut(new \DateTime($data['debut']));
$reservation -> setFin(new \DateTime($data['fin']));

//On enregistre la reservation dans la base de donnée

$em->persist($reservation);
$em->flush();

return new JsonResponse(['status' => 'success']);

 }
```

And the mistake I encounter is the one:

```
  App\Entity\Reservation object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation.
```

What I did to solve this error was to look at the route I was calling in the Ajax request to see if it was correctly named and I also looked at the format of se that I was sending with the Ajax request, but the error is still displayed

Comment: As from the error looks it cannot convert parameter. this link can be helpful https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html#doctrine-converter

Also you are checking in controller if method is post? and as you described before route already accepts only POST request so your check is not needed. 

And I Recommend you to follow PSR-2 and PSR-12 coding standards.